# Textbox positioned on a image, not selectable in IE8

Tags: image, for-loop, textbox

I needed a background image for a searchbar, something similar to fotolia.com.
so I positioned an image in the required location and then relatively positioned a textbox on it and then set background:transparent on the textbox so that the image would be visible through textbox...

this works fine in FF and chrome... Its possible to select the textbox and start typing in it..

In IE8.. the textbox is present but it isnt selectable using the mouse... But if you use the TAB button, the textbox gets selected and I can type in it...
The only problem is in IE which is the textbox is not selectable to type in it...

pls note: z-index doesnt seem to be the problem, and precautionary, I have kept it on high..

can anyone help..

thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably not position a transparent textbox, but rather set the `background-image` of the textbox.

```
input[type="text"] { background-image: url(foo.png); }
```

Alternatively, you can position the `<input>` *within* a `<div>` or other block element and give it the background image, but not *on top of* an `<img>`.